# Rails AJAX rendering error ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'object')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am creating a search bar for some objects which are called `notification groups` using ajax. When I attempt to search for objects using ajax I get the following error in my console:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `notification_group' for #<#<Class:0x00007f6e94496f38>:0x00007f6e8c415508>):
```

My search form is the following view code below:

```
 - if @notification_groups.present?
  #search_bar
    = form_tag :search_notification_groups, id: 'search_form', method: :get, remote: true do
      = text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: 'Search by friendly name'
      = hidden_field_tag :per_page, @per_page
      = submit_tag 'Search', id: 'btn_note_group_search'
```

Following my view code, I have this piece of view code that renders the objects for the index page:

```
  -if @notification_groups.size > 0
    = render partial: 'notification_group', collection: @notification_groups
```

And the partial code is the following. It basically a table with `<tr>` rows:

```
%tr.ng_list
%td
    = check_box_tag "ids[]", notification_group.id, false, class: 'check_box', id: notification_group.id, 'data-group-name' => notification_group.friendly_name
  %td
    = link_to notification_group.friendly_name, notification_group_path(@ssl_slug, notification_group.id)
  %td
    = link_to notification_group.scan_logs.count, notification_group_scan_logs_path(@ssl_slug, notification_group.id)
  %td
    = notification_group.disable ? "Disabled" : "Enabled"
```

My code works fine with HTML, however when I try to implement my search with Ajax, the error appears that there is no variable `notification_group`, which is the local variable.

Here is my controller code:

```
  def search
    @notification_groups = NotificationGroup.friendly_name(params[:search]).paginate(@p)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :index }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

The accompanying `search.js.erb` code is a simple line that should render the partial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ng_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'notification_group', collection: @notification_groups) %>")
})
```

I've checked the rails documentation and this is how the `search.js.erb` file should work. However, it errors out with a 500 error and does not make changes to the html file. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `search.js.erb` with following

```
$(".ng_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render @notification_groups) %>")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit. It didn't throw an error but it also didn't update the view. Maybe I can refine my approach with this.

Comment: In your browser's developer console check the response and share across.